# how do you add a class and change css in javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the css rgba and reload the class fadeInUpBig ....., i am currently using the javascript ...

```
<script>          
$('.tile.bg-darkBlue').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
     setTimeout(function(){
       $("#colorscreen").css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)');
       $("fadeInUpBig").replaceWith("fadeInUpBig");
        $(".tile-group.one").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    }, 1000);

});
</script>
```

The replacewith is a poor attempt at reloading the fadeInUpBig once the color has been changed. any help would be really usefull.

I HAVE RE-EDITED THE LATEST VERSION THAT ALSO DOESN'T WORK .... PUTTING DOTS BEFORE THE CLASS IS NOT REQURIED TO MY UNDERSTANDING HERE IS THE LATEST

```
<script>          
$('.tile.bg-darkBlue').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
     setTimeout(function(){
       $("#colorscreen").reloadClass("fadeInUpBig").css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)');

        $(".tile-group.one").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    }, 1000);

});
```

jsfiddle is down at the moment so can't post it

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/7-code-playgrounds/

Comment: fadeInUpBig references nothing.  You need a dot ('.') in front of it if it is a css class

Comment: it is a class but have been told you don't need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replaceWith you could try

```
$(".fadeInUpBig").hide().fadeIn('fast');
```

**Edit:**
Also, I'm not sure if it's a class, but I added the dot for you.

Comment: nope didn't work , the class fadeInUpBig is a css animation so that class needs to happen again

Comment: that might be very helpful will try now so you get rid of the class and then put it back in

Comment: Also, you could always try removeClass - addClass

Comment: If the link I provided didn't help, create a function to animate the class and call the function on $(".fadeInUpBig"). Basically manually reanimate it.

Comment: still no change even with the dot in front

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77912/discussion-between-user3504751-and-tony-h).